# Unable to locate the package: handle_detector

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am not able to locate the package [handle_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/handle_detector) in the repositories for ros indigo, although in the Ros Wiki say that it sould there be for indigo.

Morevoer, If I try to compile it from the source I get this error:

```
CMake Error at handle_detector/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen" with any of
  the following names:

    EigenConfig.cmake
    eigen-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I don't have high knowledge of c++ and ros. I understand that it doesn't find the package Eigen, but I have installed all the ros packages of Eigen:

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-eigen-*

And moreover I also have the Eigen library installied in my pc.

I Have no idea how to fix the problem. I just want to use that package and whatever method (by repository or by source) is ok for me.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213058/unable-to-locate-the-package:-handle_detector/) by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When linking to Eigen, the problem is that Eigen does not provide a proper CMake module in order to find the location of the libraries, so that  `EigenConfig.cmake` or `eigen-config.cmake` cannot be found.

Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018447/using-eigen-library-in-ros-indigo

Additionally, I do not know how it works, but not all packages in the wiki can be found through `apt-get`, it is common that you have to use some of them from source.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2015-07-08**:
Thanks, that resolved the problem :)

Moreover, If I only change in the CMakeLists.txt the Eigen with Eigen3 is working without any further changes.